# Errors in mpreal.h when using mpfr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, eigen, mpfr

i'm trying to use mpfr with eigen (MPRealSupport) for some calculations.

When i try to compile my prog in VS2010 (yes i know it's old, but i don't have any choice in the matter) i get the following errors (sorry they are in german. I can't change the language of VS):

```
1>C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal\mpreal.h(2607): error C2660: 'mpfr::urandom': Funktion akzeptiert keine 1 Argumente
1>C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal\mpreal.h(2630): error C2665: "mpfr::grandom": Durch keine der 2 Überladungen konnten alle Argumenttypen konvertiert werden.
1>          C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal\mpreal.h(474): kann 'const mpfr::mpreal mpfr::grandom(unsigned int)' sein
1>          bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(gmp_randstate_t)'
1>  Zone.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal\mpreal.h(2607): error C2660: 'mpfr::urandom': Funktion akzeptiert keine 1 Argumente
1>C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal\mpreal.h(2630): error C2665: "mpfr::grandom": Durch keine der 2 Überladungen konnten alle Argumenttypen konvertiert werden.
1>          C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal\mpreal.h(474): kann 'const mpfr::mpreal mpfr::grandom(unsigned int)' sein
1>          bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(gmp_randstate_t)'
```

A rough translation is:

mpreal.h(2607): error C2660: 'mpfr::urandom':function dosn't accept 1 argument

mpreal.h(2630): error C2665: "mpfr::grandom": through non of the 2 overlodings could all argumenttypes be converted

mpreal.h(474): can be 'const mpfr::mpreal mpfr::grandom(unsigned int)'
         with adjustment of argument list '(gmp_randstate_t)'

i have absolutely no idea how to solve these errors.

any tips?

thanks....

**EDIT:**

OK, here is an mini example that produces said error...

header:

```
#pragma once

#include <Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\Eigen\MPRealSupport>
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <mpreal.h>
class test {
public:
    test();
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

test::test(){
}
```

And those are my include paths:

- $(QTDIR)\include;
- $(QTDIR)\include\qtmain;
- $(QTDIR)\include\QtCore;
- C:\Program Files\Itasca\Flac3d500\pluginfiles\interface;
- C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\mpfr_mpir_x86_x64_msvc2010\mpfr;  *(mpfr.h)*
- C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\Doku_eigen-eigen-07105f7124f9\unsupported\test\mpreal;  *(MPRealSupport)*
- C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra;C:\Program Files\CPP_Extra\mpfr_mpir_x86_x64_msvc2010\mpir\dll\x64\Release;  *(gmp.h)*

**Edit 2**

OK, i got the errors by getting the newest Eigen and mpfr c++.

But now i get LINK2019 errors...

```
Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_get_default_rounding_mode" in Funktion ""public: static enum mpfr_rnd_t __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::get_default_rnd(void)" (?get_default_rnd@mpreal@mpfr@@SA?AW4mpfr_rnd_t@@XZ)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_get_default_prec" in Funktion ""public: static long __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::get_default_prec(void)" (?get_default_prec@mpreal@mpfr@@SAJXZ)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_clear" in Funktion ""private: void __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::clear(struct __mpfr_struct *)" (?clear@mpreal@mpfr@@AEAAXPEAU__mpfr_struct@@@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_set_default_prec" in Funktion ""public: static void __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::set_default_prec(long)" (?set_default_prec@mpreal@mpfr@@SAXJ@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_init2" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::mpreal(void)" (??0mpreal@mpfr@@QEAA@XZ)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_swap" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::mpreal(class mpfr::mpreal &&)" (??0mpreal@mpfr@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_set_d" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::mpreal(double,long,enum mpfr_rnd_t)" (??0mpreal@mpfr@@QEAA@NJW4mpfr_rnd_t@@@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_set_si" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::mpreal(int,long,enum mpfr_rnd_t)" (??0mpreal@mpfr@@QEAA@HJW4mpfr_rnd_t@@@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_set4" in Funktion ""public: class mpfr::mpreal & __cdecl mpfr::mpreal::operator=(class mpfr::mpreal const &)" (??4mpreal@mpfr@@QEAAAEAV01@AEBV01@@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_add" in Funktion ""class mpfr::mpreal const __cdecl mpfr::operator+(class mpfr::mpreal const &,class mpfr::mpreal const &)" (??Hmpfr@@YA?BVmpreal@0@AEBV10@0@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_sub" in Funktion ""class mpfr::mpreal const __cdecl mpfr::operator-(class mpfr::mpreal const &,class mpfr::mpreal const &)" (??Gmpfr@@YA?BVmpreal@0@AEBV10@0@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_mul" in Funktion ""class mpfr::mpreal const __cdecl mpfr::operator*(class mpfr::mpreal const &,class mpfr::mpreal const &)" (??Dmpfr@@YA?BVmpreal@0@AEBV10@0@Z)".
1>Zone.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "mpfr_cmp_si_2exp" in Funktion ""bool __cdecl mpfr::operator<=(class mpfr::mpreal const &,int)" (??Nmpfr@@YA_NAEBVmpreal@0@H@Z)".
1>C:\Users\mpohl\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EclToF3grid\x64\Release\fishecltof3grid005_64.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 13 nicht aufgelöste externe Verweise.
```

They are unresolved external referneces

Comment: It's most likely nothing wrong with the header files, but with how *you* use the header files and the library. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be really hard to say anything.

Comment: well that's gonna be tough. I have a 2500 line long code, that is only partly written by me and i have no idea where the error originates. By the way, i could compile this with gcc on my arch linux.

Comment: What version of mpfr are you using on Linux and Windows? Are they the same?

Comment: Does a simple `#include <unsupported/Eigen/MPRealSupport>` cause the same error (regarding providing a MCVE ...)? Also, which Eigen version are you using?

Comment: Linux version: mpfr-3.1.5.p2-1

Comment: Linux version: mpfr-3.1.5.p2-1     ;       Windows version: mpfr 3.0.1 (x64) ; Eigen on Linux: eigen-3.3.3-1     ;      Eigen on Windows: eigen  3.2.8
 (maybe, not sure...)

Comment: chtz's implied hint, that i should check the version did help. I got a newer version of mpfr and Eigen and the errors are gone. But now i have new errors. I will post them in my initial staement....

Comment: You need to link your project to the mpfr binaries, something like `mpfr.lib` or `mpfr.dll`

Comment: that did the trick. So, who gets credit for the answer? ggael or chtz? Thank you both anyway.....